# Exact Matching in Dialogflow

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chat, dialogflow-es, matching

I'm trying to get dialogflow to only return a value if the match is exact. My example:

The command is **!help** however if you type "**help**" or have it in a sentence, it will also return the results. I am wanting it to only return the results when **!help** is used.

Comment: need more details and some code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set ML classification threshold in agent settings to 1.0
In your case it would be also better to choose Hybrid match mode, but I think this is default option.

Another option is to create new entity with value **!help** and check **Regexp entity** option. In the intent add user add user expression **!help** - it should be recognized as defined entity. I have tested this and the agent triggers for !help but not for help.

[image: Entity in Dialogflow]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but I'm afraid neither of those work, it still triggers when I type the word by itself without the !

Comment: @Frazer Please see my edit, I have added another solution.

Comment: I'm afraid the edit doesn't work for me as it doesn't allow for symbols in the Entities section.

Comment: Maybe it was special character in the entity name? I didn't have such issue (see screenshot).

Comment: Ah, it was! So I can now add the Entity, however when adding the training phrase, it doesn't come up as already being an entity.

Comment: You can annotate training phrase manually - just select !help text and choose entity.

Comment: You have to double click in the training phrase. All sorted. Thank you!!